# How do Fn keys work?

Tags: kernel, shortcut-keys, events

I like to know how <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys work in my laptop.
I think a kernel module exist that catch <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and call some scripts to do something.
In my laptop, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> switch power of wireless and blue-tooth.

this is output of `acpi_listen`, when i press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

```
hotkey ATKD 0000005d 00000019
hotkey ATKD 0000007e 00000009
```

and, folloing is output of `xev` for <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

```
keycode 238 press
keycode 238 release
keycode 237 press
keycode 237 release
```

I guess whenever i pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> two events are jumped out. I tried to find what actions are executed for this keys.
any idea appreciated ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*Synetech* gives a very readable explanation about the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys [here](https://superuser.com/questions/294155/why-does-the-fn-key-on-my-laptop-not-work-when-used-with-an-external-keyboard)

> ## Technical Details
>
> When you press a key on a keyboard, the keyboard controller (a small
>   **IC chip** *inside* the keyboard) detects the electrical circuit and
>   processes it to decode which key was pressed and then sends the
>   [*scancode*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode) to the **motherboard**. The operating system receives
>   scancode from the **BIOS** and then performs whatever action it needs to
>   in order to process that keypress.
>
> With most keys, this is simple enough. If you press the <kbd>A</kbd>
>   key, its keyboard controller sends the scancode to the motherboard
>   which then passes it to the **OS** which in turn usually prints 'A'. (If
>   the OS detects that one of the modifier keys is currently held down,
>   then it may do something different. In fact, you can configure it to
>   do whatever you want when the <kbd>A</kbd> key is pressed with or
>   without modifiers.)
>
> Now the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is special. When you press it by itself,
>   nothing happens because it is *exclusively* a modifier key and is not
>   (generally) meant to do anything on its own. When you hold it and
>   press another key, the keyboard controller detects that and looks in
>   its built-in table to see if it is a known combination. If the combo
>   is not in the table, then it just ignores it, but if the combo is in
>   the table, then it looks up the associated scancode and sends that.
>
> What does the OS end up seeing? It does **not** see the scancode for
>   the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and the scancode for the other key. Instead, it
>   sees a single scancode associated with whatever function the Fn-combo
>   has been set to. For example, if the laptop manufacturer has set the
>   <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> combo to reduce the volume, then
>   the OS sees the scancode associated with the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>,
>   which some keyboards actually have.

Also note that the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key works [*independently*](http://support.lenovo.com/en_FI/diagnose-and-fix/detail.page?DocID=HT002061) from the operating system.

Moreover, [this article](http://jablonskis.org/2012/linux-and-samsung-series-laptop-9-fn-keys/) may help point you in the right direction:

> The kernel has its own `scancode` to
>   `keycode` mapping table, so it maps a certain scancode to a
>   keycode. You can look into /usr/include/linux/input.h to see what your
>   kernel uses for scancode to keycode mapping – it is called a
>   `keymap`.

---

***Postscript***

I might need to somewhat renege on the earlier claim that the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys work entirely *independently* of the OS; without going into more technical details here, the upshot seems to be that your OS might not "support" all or some of your keyboard's <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys, see, for instance:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/extra_keyboard_keys
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274715/blue-fn-function-keys-not-working-with-lubuntu-on-my-thinkpad

Comment: Thanks, interesting information about Fn keys,
Actually I want find what part of OS handle `scancode` associated with, for example, "keycode 238".

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://jablonskis.org/2012/linux-and-samsung-series-laptop-9-fn-keys/) can help point you in the right direction? *"The kernel has its own `scancode` to `keycode` mapping table, so it maps a certain scancode to a keycode. You can look into /usr/include/linux/input.h to see what your kernel uses for scancode to keycode mapping – it is called a `keymap`."*

Comment: That article is perfect, This is what I'm looking for