# Fn function on Das Keyboard Model S doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, xev

I tried to test `Fn` with `xev` — pressing it or any combination like `Fn + F1` for `Mute` doesn't show anything in output.

What can I do?

Comment: I believe you can find your answer on this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270416/how-do-fn-keys-work/270428#270428 From what I can tell from what nutty writes in his answer, the Fn key doesn't have any output since it's exclusively a modifier key.

Comment: @Nil I forgot to mention it, but pressing combination with `Fn` like `Fn + F1` for `Mute` doesn't show up in `xev` either.