# Configuring hotkeys for Fn combinations not recognised by acpi_listen

Tags: 14.10, acpi, shortcut-keys

Some of the *Fn* combinations of my laptop work, some do not. I tried to manually configure the missing key bindings, but `acpi_listen` has no output when I hit the keys. Is there any possibility to configure them?

Comment: Have you seen this [How do Fn keys work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270416/how-do-fn-keys-work). Could you add some info about brand/model of laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a old keyboard that i configured the action keys manually, open **SYSTEM SETTINGS > KEYBOARDS > SHORTCUTS**. Here you will find the option **Custom Shortcuts**.

I hope to help you.