# Thinkpad T440s internal mic not working in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sound, 15.04, pulseaudio, thinkpad, microphone

My internal microphone on my thinkpad t440s is not picking up any audio on Ubuntu 15.04. For reference, here is the output of lspci and my kernel I am running.

```
philip@philip:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-V (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

And here is my kernel

```
philip@philip:~$ uname -r
3.19.0-15-generic
```

Would anyone have any suggestion of things to do?

Comment: Perhaps post a few GUI screenshots from ~ system > sound(s)? I'd assume the mic is not "switched on" or selected properly. *How* did you try to test it? What does `arecord -l` say? -- For extensive troubleshooting on this see http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/sound/sound_troubleshooting.htm and also try `arecord -d 10 /tmp/test-mic.wav` followed by `aplay /tmp/test-mic.wav` from http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-test-microphone-with-audio-linux-sound-architecture-alsa

Comment: 'Here is a screenshot from my sound setting for input of my microphone. http://i.imgur.com/NXup0wE.png Now the problem is when I make any noise, or yell at the mic, there is no sound that moves on the sound spectrum graph. This is how I tested it, as well as running it on skype, as well as the sound recorder. Here is the output for the commands, and when I ran aplay I did not hear any of the sound that should have been heard. http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12109618/

Comment: Judging by the [looks](http://www.lenovo.com/images/gallery/1060x596/lenovo-laptop-thinkpad-t440s-overhead-keyboard-2.jpg) you can "mute" your mic input with [Fn-keys](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270416/how-do-fn-keys-work). Have you tried toggling this "mic mute" ?

Comment: By a few GUI screenshots of "sound" I meant a few: e.g. also while sound is playing, and also from the "applications" tab (while sound is playing).

Comment: ? question abandoned ?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the [looks](http://www.lenovo.com/images/gallery/1060x596/lenovo-laptop-thinkpad-t440s-overhead-keyboard-2.jpg) you can "mute" your mic input with [Fn-keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270416/how-do-fn-keys-work). Have you tried toggling this "mic mute" ?