# How to enable monitor from terminal?

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, display

I accidentally disabled my monitors, so when I log in I land on a blank, back-lit screen. I can open terminals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>, so how do I enable the monitor from terminal?

I tried `xrandr`, but it can't open display. `xset` does not work either. I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261122/how-to-reset-monitor-settings-to-default-through-terminal) which closely resembles my problem. The answer provides a script to be put in `/etc/X11/Xreset.d`.

Running it does not solve my problem (though it is likely I don't understand how to use it properly). I think I somehow made the new default to be "disable monitors".

Running Ubuntu Studio 13.10. I do not have nVidia drivers. I can't find an `xorg.conf` file to remove. Thankful for any and all input!

- Output of command `xrandr -d :0`:

  ```
  Screen 0: minimum 320x200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
  LVDS1 connected 1366x768+-32768+-32768 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 192mm
      1366x768    60.0*
      1360x768    59.8    60.0
      1024x768    60.0
      800x600     60.3    56.2
      640x480     59.9
  VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  ```

  Still being a CLI beginner I fail to understand from `man xrandr` how to switch on (there is an off option) or enable displays.
- Output of:

  ```
  xrandr --auto
  ```

  is:

  ```
  Can't open display
  ```
- Output of `xrandr -d :0 --auto`:

  ```
  Configure crtc 0 failed
  ```

  Maybe I just have to reinstall X11?
- Outputs of suggested commands / which `xset` commands I tried:

  ```
  $xrandr -d :0 output LVDS1 --auto
  configure crtc 0 failed
  ```

  `xset q` and `xset dpms force on` both return:

  ```
  unable to open display ''''
  ```

No difference for `sudo` commands.

More futile attempts and the potential discovery of a security issue:

1. I've tried to reinstall Xorg and X11, then I ran:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver*
   ```

   which failed with this output:

   ```
   (many versions of this:)
       Note, selecting 'xserver-xorg-something' for regex 'xserver*'
   (next:)
       Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
       requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
       distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
       or been moved out of Incoming.

       The following information may help to resolve the situation:

       The following packages have unmet dependencies:
       xserver-xorg-input-mtrack : Conflicts: xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
       but 1.0~rc2+git20110312-2build4 is to be installed
       E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```
2. Next I logged in as guest and logged in as myself through TTY <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> and ran the same `xrand` commands as above, with the same output as far as I can see.
3. Then I created a new user with full admin rights and repeated 4.2 via TTY.
4. SECURITY ISSUE? No, just a need of awareness. Not related to this subject, details at [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/242460).

It begins looking like a system reinstall is necessary.

Comment: Try xrandr from the Ctrl-Alt-F1 virtual terminal again, but this time add an explicit display argument e.g. `xrandr -d :0`

Comment: `xrandr -d :0 --auto` ?

Comment: What `xset` commands did you try?

Comment: You need to specify an output device for the --auto directive e.g. `xrandr -d :0 --output LVDS1 --auto`

Comment: For xset, see edit #3

Comment: I also can't run most xrandr commands from VT. Typically `--auto` or `--off` won't work, while `--primary` works and actually works around another bug. I'm using Gentoo on Lenovo T420s, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Figure out that the offending settings are stored in a file called `displays.xml`.

   I won't detail here how I guessed it, though the comment about deleting `monitors.xml` proved helpful. It also involved manual comparing of several .config subdirectories.

   Of course, what I **should** have done was ask my search engine "*where does xubuntu store display settings*" and find [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2168804) at ubuntuforums...
2. Log in to your blank display and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> to enter command line.
3. `sudo find . -type f -name "*displays*"`
4. `mv ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml.bak`
5. `sudo reboot`

I hope this quest may help somebody.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to get around the `xrandr` from VT issue, does it?

Comment: But answers "how to enable monitor from terminal"

Answer (score 22):

After running this command switch immediately to  the tty where the screen is black, and after 5 seconds the screen should show up.

```
sleep 5 && xrandr -d :0 --output LVDS --auto
```

The `xrandr command` will turn on your main screen. It only seems to work if you're currently on the tty where your display manager is run, hence the `sleep` to give you some time to be able to switch.

Comment: Brilliant in its simplicity. Solved my problem.

Comment: What it does? Waits for 5 secs and then what?

Comment: Then it runs xrandr (required command), while you switch back to graphical virtual console tty7 (:0 display), that you want to turn on again.
That worked for me.

Comment: This guy saved me.

1. Login to TTY by using ctrl-alt-F1
2. Run his sleep ... command
3. ctrl-alt-F7 to return to my blank screen before the 5 seconds are up
4. the screen appears after 5 seconds!

Comment: Somewhat similar approach (on MX Linux 17) via ssh:  ssh to the computer (I had to `sudo apt install openssh-server` before in VT1), ctrl-alt-F7 (on the computer itself, to be on the graphical console which happens to be VT7 in my case). Then, in the ssh session: `export DISPLAY=:0.0`, `xrandr -display :0.0 --output eDP-1 --auto`.

Comment: Note that `LVDS` is specific and your display may be named something different. Find out with `xrandr -d :0 -q` from @steeldriver's answer.

Comment: In my case it failed with `LVDS` so just removed the `--output LVDS` and it worked

Comment: It worked but you can avoid the sleep by using the `chvt` command like mentioned in the answer of cyberbrain.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to open (and set properties for) a display via the virtual terminal console provided you know the *display number* for the running X session. That's usually :0 for the primary physical display but that's not always the case. For example, to query display :0

```
xrandr -d :0 -q
```

To re-enable a display that's been turned off, it's usually sufficient to use the `--auto` e.g. to turn the LVDS1 output device on display :0 back on

```
xrandr -d :0 --output LVDS1 --auto
```

Comment: Output of this command is the same as in edit #2 in my question. See edit #3

Comment: Perhaps we should take a step back - how exactly did you "accidentally disable" your monitors?

Comment: I had connected a projector. When finished watching I opened display settings, chose the projector entry and clicked "do not use this" (don't remember exact wording). I'm not sure if I accidentally clicked on both, anyway my screen went blank. Can't remember for sure now if I used tty login to reboot (I think I did) or if I did a hard reboot by power button.

Comment: Have you tried moving or renaming your ~/.config/monitors.xml file (e.g. `mv ~/.config/monitors.xml ~/.config/monitors.xml.bak`)? BTW does logging into to a different account or guest account work?

Comment: I don't find a ~/.config/monitors.xml file on my system.

Comment: Guest account is working fine. I can also use my profile through advanced options in the boot menu. Choosing recovery mode, then resuming normal boot. This gives a warning that some graphical drivers may not load properly, ironically meaning it works for me, without possibilities to change resolution, etc.

Comment: This worked for me when I used `sleep 5 && ...` before it, then switched to the main screen before the 5 seconds were up (from @Martin  Marcan's answer)

Answer (score 3):

I would extend the answer of Martin Marčan by replacing the sleep with a command that switches to the black console:

```
chvt 7 && xrandr -d :0 --output LVDS --auto
```

where 7 is the number of the console used for X11 (usually 7 or 8) and LVDS is the name of the output you want to reconfigure. You can retrieve the list of outputs first with

```
xrandr -d :0
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem in Lubuntu 18.04 like this:

If you boot into a screen, which is turned of, open a terminal blindly with <kbd>CTR</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>. Since you cannot see the terminal and what you write, type very carefully

```
xrandr --output "nameYourScreen" --auto
```

Hit Enter. Voila.

(BTW: In my case, entering such code in tty1 or any virtual terminal did not work. I tried various things, people mention above, but when switching back to the running session or after reboot, nothing changed. Maybe the problem is that xrandr can execute this command properly for some hardware only within a running x-session ?)

Answer (score 1):

This works for enable two external monitors on my computer (Ubuntu with i3wm):

```
xrandr --auto
```

That turns on all the monitors.

Then I disable the duplicate desktop and setup the resolution (eDP-1 - my laptop monitor, DP-1-1 and DP-1-2 - my external monitors connected via thunderbolt):

```
xrandr --output DP-1-2 --mode 1920x1080 --left-of eDP-1
xrandr --output DP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --left-of DP-1-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xrandr --output "nameYourVGA" --mode "yourResolution"
```

For example:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1366x768
```

See if that works.