# Activate display via console tty?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I have a custom xrandr script which enables my external monitors and disables my laptop's monitor. When I disconnect my external monitor, I can't enable the monitor because my screen is blank.

I'd love to be able to access my console tty (ctrl-alt-f1), and trigger xrandr to go on (i.e.  `xrandr --output eDP1 --auto`). Running that in my tty says "Can't open display". Any tips for how I can do that?

Comment: Why not simply create a keyboard shortcut, calling the command? the command? (System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts > )

Comment: I'll have to test it out to make sure my screensaver doesn't capture the key press, but thanks. I'll report back.

Comment: I just tested to make sure, made xrandr shut off my screen, re enable by keyboard shortcut :)

Comment: If you *know* the X screen number you should be able to give it explicitly using xrandr's `-d` (`--display`) parameter e.g. `xrandr -d :0 --output eDP1 --auto`

Comment: Thing is the Unity Settings Daemon does automatically reconfigure screens for some graphics cards. For instance I've an   Intel graphics card on one laptop which does reconfigure my monitor automatically once i unplug VGA cable, but on the other ( AMD ) it doesn't automatically reconfigure it.   Try running `dbus-monitor --profile "type='signal'" | grep '.*MonitorChanged.*'` command  see if it detects MonitorChanged signal when you disable that signal and let me know.  ( You can use Ctrl + C to stop that command by the way )

Comment: @Serg exactly, I have two systems, one does, the other doesn' switch on the remaining monitor.

Comment: @JacobVlijm what kind of cards do they have , if you don't mind me asking ?

Comment: @Serg I don't mind :), but I am unable to check atm :)

Comment: @steeldriver I get the error `xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed` when running that. The `-d :0` works in a display-enabled console though.

Comment: @JustinAbrahms hi , did you see my comment ? Can you please try running the command I posted previously ?

Comment: I don't use unity, unfortunately.

Comment: @JustinAbrahms what do you use then ? Gnome ?

Comment: I'm using Xmonad.

Comment: This answer might be helpful for those looking at the above question: https://askubuntu.com/a/839371/129295. If I understand correctly, the idea is to use sleep in order to have time to switch to the graphical console before xrandr is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to go into console, you could achieve the same by adding a custom keyboard shortcut to re- enable your internal screen.

Choose System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts, click the + and add the command to a shortcut of your choice:

```
xrandr --output <screenname> --auto
```

Just tested it on my system (laptop, 15.10); switched off my screen and successfully re- enabled it with the keyboard shortcut, running the command :)

#### Alternatively

You could use an edited version of [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/740140/72216). The version below (small background script, is checking once per four seconds if an external screen is connected) makes sure your internal screen is switched on

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
# --- set your internal screen below (the example is my primary screen)
internal = "DVI-I-1"
#---

# don't change anything below
scr_info1 = 0

while True:
    time.sleep(4)
    # read the current screen setup from xrandr
    get_screens = subprocess.check_output("xrandr").decode("utf-8").splitlines()
    scr_data = [l for l in get_screens if " connected " in l]
    # count the number of connected screens
    scr_info2  = len(scr_data)
    # if the number of connected screens changes, 
    # switch off the internal one if there are two screens
    if scr_info2 != scr_info1:
        if scr_info2 == 2:
            ext = [s.split()[0] for s in scr_data if not internal in s][0]
            subprocess.Popen(["xrandr", "--output", internal, "--off", "--output", ext, "--auto"])
        else:
            subprocess.Popen(["xrandr", "--output", internal, "--auto"])

    scr_info1 = scr_info2
```

#### How to setup

1. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `switch_screens.py`
2. In the head section of your script, set the name of your *internal* screen. To find out, open a terminal window and run the command `xrandr` (no external screen connected) The line with "connected" in it shows the name of your screen in the first string, looking like: `VGA-1` or something like that.
3. Test- run it by opening a terminal window and typ the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/switch_screens.py
   ```

   While the script runs, connect your external screen, wait for you internal screen to switch of and disconnect again.
4. If all works fine, add the command below to Startup Applications: open Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/switch_screens.py"
   ```

Log out and back in. Now your internal screen is switched off automatically if an external screen is connected, re- enabling it if you disconnect.

The script adds no noticeable burden at all to your system.

Comment: My screensaver (i3lock) captures this keybinding, so I'm unable to actually trigger it, unfortunately.

Comment: @JustinAbrahms huh? A screensaver capturing a keybinding? How can that be?

Comment: Well, the screensaver is password protected. It doesn't register the Ctrl+F12 I bound to the shortcut.

Comment: @JustinAbrahms Then first type the password , return...

Comment: @JustinAbrahms with a small edit of this one http://askubuntu.com/a/740140/72216 your internal screen could be re enabled after disconnecting automatically. Care for an edit?

Comment: @JustinAbrahms see my update

Comment: That makes sense, but also seems like more than a little bit of a hack. Really hoping there's a better answer here, but you certainly get an upvote and if nothing by Monday.. the checkmark thing. :)