# Getting stuck when installing Nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, graphics, additional-drivers

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop with GTX 1070, I want to install Nvidia driver via **Additional drivers** tools in Ubuntu, however it gets stuck at this stage. I don't know what to do now and it looks that it will take forever to apply changes. What can I do?

Comment: Please follow these instructions -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/885422/ubuntu-16-04-dell-xps-15-does-not-detect-external-monitor-using-hdmi/888901#888901 ! Good luck ... :)