# HDMI not working on Dell XPS 15 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, dell, hdmi

I'm trying to attach a second, external monitor to a Dell XPS 15 laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 using an HDMI cable.

The monitor does not show up in Ubuntu at all.

So far I tried the following from that question: [Ubuntu 16.04 Dell XPS 15 does not detect external Monitor using HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885422/ubuntu-16-04-dell-xps-15-does-not-detect-external-monitor-using-hdmi)

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455`
- Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`
- `sudo update-grub`

Still the monitor is not detected at all (see `xrandr` output below).

If I don't set `nouveau.modeset=0` after installing Nvidia drivers, the primary (internal) monitor will turn black during boot and I can use virtual terminals only.

Am I missing an important step here?

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30e (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
3b:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation Device 0116
```

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.98    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18 to 20. On 18, I was able to use an external monitor using the XPS's USB-C port. (I can't test if this still works on 20, because I don't have the monitor here.)

I can't set the output manually using `xrandr` since the HDMI outputs are not detected at all:

```
$ xrandr --verbose --output eDP-1-1 --mode 3840x2160 --output HDMI-1 --left-of eDP-1 --mode auto
warning: output HDMI-1 not found; ignoring
crtc 0:    3840x2160  60.00 +0+0 "eDP-1-1"
```

The `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package is already installed.

Comment: Fresh install of a laptop perchance? AMD or intel? The drivers that ubuntu automatically installed are probably not sufficient for your device. Follow instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284567/cannot-connect-second-monitor-via-hdmi-cable-in-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: @Pascal The Dell XPS has an Intel CPU. I added some details to my question regarding the install.

Comment: Does your night light and or brightness adjustment work?

Comment: @Pascal Yes, both

Comment: @Pascal Installing the Intel amdgpu drivers as described in your other answer leads to a black screen on X11 start (with a flickering mouse cursor).